# Which IDEs have good support for programming with CUDA?

Tags: c, windows, macos, ide, cuda

I'm starting to do programming with CUDA C. Are there any IDE that are especially good for programming with it?

I'm using a windows machine and a personal macbook :D (But I want to know what people use in linux and mac also)

Comment: You can program without any IDE. At least this is what I do under Linux (just using `emacs`, `make`, `gcc`, `gdb`, `grep`, `ctags`, `git`).

Comment: Yes, but IMXO good debugger integration and syntax highlighting improves your codding=)

Comment: You can very much program without any ide.  But, good auto completion and refactoring support goes a long way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used CUDA 2.1, and VS2008, and haven't had any problems. Just make sure after you install the toolkit and the SDK, that you do the following:

- Open "My Computer" (or explorer, or whatever) and navigate to C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA CUDA SDK\common
- Double-click on cutil_vc90.sln (assuming you're using CUDA 2.1 and VS2008); when the solution loads up, you will see a drop-down menu for the build configuration. If you are on a 64-bit platform, you need to change this from Win32 to x64.
- Build the solution.
- Look up top again -- you should see the build configuration menu that says "Debug". Change it to "Release" and build the solution again.
- Close Visual Studio.
- Back in the explorer window, find the file "paramgl_vc90.sln". Double-click it to open that solution.
- Repeat the same configuration setup and build process as described above, then close Visual Studio.

At this point, you should be able to compile the SDK projects; if you are using VS2008, make sure you open the solutions ending in _vc90.sln. Again, if you're on x64, you need to also make sure to set the build platform to "x64" in that drop-down menu.

If you get this far, and you're ready to write your own projects, check out the "template" project that comes with the SDK. You should be able to make a copy of that and use it for your own stuff, with the compiler settings (for CUDA, that is) already set up.

there is a thread on nvidia for this as well http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=91057

Answer (score 6):

Definitely the better way to code CUDA in Windows right now is Nsight Visual Studio Edition environment. With the release of CUDA 5, comes also the Nvidia Nsight Eclipse Edition, with the same programming capabilities but with the IDE of Eclipse. Nsight Eclipse Edition is available on Linux and MacOS (but not Windows). You can try it already with the **CUDA 5 release candidate** : http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit

Comment: Is it any good? How does it compare to the VS plugin?

Comment: I haven't used the VS version yet, but I strongly suspect that it will be far better than the Eclipse edition. The text editor is as good as any other, but the configuring the compiler toolchain is a huge pain on the Eclipse edition.

Answer (score 4):

In windows you can use [NVIDIA Parallel Nsight](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-parallel-nsight) Visual Studio solution. I think there is no better alternative for GPU development on windows. And `Linux + GPU development == SUX`.
There are some attempts to make some [Linux distro](http://www.fixstars.com/en/news/2010/20100302.html) which would be GPU-development friendly, but given that these are first steps to this goal - I don't expect too much from this product. (Also they have broken links)

Comment: Manjaro is pretty good for working with the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Under my Win7 I use MSVS 10 with NVidia debugger and Parallel Nsight integrated. I have cross-platform build with cmake. It's so easy with cmake. Under Linux (I use Fedora 16) I work in QT creator because it integrates well with cmake and debugger (and looks better than other IMXO). Inder Linux you can attach NVidia debugger, too.